# How do I create a custom collision map for clickable areas on a map?

Tags: collision-detection, maps

[image: map]

Say I had a map like the one displayed above. What would be the best method of creating a collision map for each individual state where I can click individually?

Comment: Related: if you're already using a physics engine for collision detection, you could [do some image processing to turn them into physics objects](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/109216/7804).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert your image to grey-scale. Make sure you have no two states that have the same grey. (You have to tweak the image.)

Have an infrastructure that maps the grey colour to a state.

Then when you mouse-over the map, pick the pixel colour that is under the mouse pointer, and search for it in the map.

You'll know what state you want to select this way.

Comment: Wonderful solution!

Comment: Update: I managed to implement this. Now how would I go about changing the state's color when the mouse is over the state?

Comment: @BruceTheGoose Post a new question :) You can link to this one here if it's relevant.