# How can I generate vertex data from an SVG?

Tags: box2d, phaser, vector-art

I am trying out the Phaser game engine, and am interested in making a vector graphics game (simple black and white like *Asteroids*), but I want to use vector graphics instead of raster PNGs.

I was looking at [this example](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/box2d/car-on-terrain), which looks like what I want to do...

Where I am stuck is, say I draw a simple Asteroids style ship in Illustrator, consisting of 3 connected lines.  How do I export that data into an array of vertices that would work with the `setPolygon()` method in Phaser/Box2d?

Comment: I would save my vector graphics in SVG and then try to get the vertices from it with an XML reader. But there might be a better tool for that.

Comment: For physics geometry, [here's a related question on how to turn a raster image into a Box2D object](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/109216/7804) which might get you started. For rendering, perhaps you should look into [the Cairo graphics library](https://www.cairographics.org/) with [RSVG](https://developer.gnome.org/rsvg/2.40/rsvg-Using-RSVG-with-cairo.html).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following function (it's JavaScript) could help you.

The first parameter is an element of type SVG, it can be a path, rect, circle, etc. The second parameter is the distance of segments. Returns an array as a javascript object, which is generally used in Phaser or matter js.

```
function toVertex(pathSVG, n){
  let pathLength = pathSVG.getTotalLength();
  let vtx = [];
  var i = 0;
  while(i < pathLength){
    let arr =  pathSVG.getPointAtLength(i);
    vtx.push({x:arr.x, y:arr.y});
    i+=n;
  }
  return vtx;
}
```